# Change password of login page with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a login gui using tkinter, and I want a new window to open when I click on change password.

When the window opens it should prompt the user for a new password, and then change and store the password. Afterwards, it should login again using the changed password.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as tm



class LoginFrame(tk.Frame):
    storedPassword='password'
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        #storedPassword='password'
        self.label_username = tk.Label(self, text="Username")
        self.label_password = tk.Label(self, text="Password")



        self.entry_username = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_password = tk.Entry(self)#, show="*") to help us see new password

        self.label_username.grid(row=0)
        self.label_password.grid(row=1)
        self.entry_username.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.entry_password.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.logbtn = tk.Button(self, text="Login", command=self._login_btn_clicked)
        self.logbtn.grid(columnspan=2)
        newPassword = self.entry_password.get()
        print(newPassword)
        self.logbtn = tk.Button(self, text="change_password", command=self.change_password)
        self.logbtn.grid(columnspan=2)


    def change_password(self,newPassword):
        self.new_password = tk.Label(self, text="new password")
        self.entry_newpassword = tk.Entry(self)
        self.storedPassword=newPassword
        print(self.entry_newpassword.get())
    def _login_btn_clicked(self):

        username = self.entry_username.get()
        password = self.entry_password.get()



        if username == "admin":
            if password == self.storedPassword:
                tm.showinfo("Login info", "Welcome admin")
                self.storedPassword=self.entry_password.get()

            else:
                tm.showerror("Login error", "Incorrect password")
        else:
            tm.showerror("Login error", "Incorrect username")

window= tk.Tk()
lf = LoginFrame(window)
#root = tk.Tk()
#newWindow= LoginFrame(root)

#root.mainloop()
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply destroy the initial window first using window.destroy() and then create a new window in a function when it is called by the button. Continue adding entry widgets and labels as you know and get the new password and run another function to go back to initial page after using root.destroy() to remove change password window.

Here is a simple code showing what I just said:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

storedPassword = 'password'

def loginok(username,password):
    global storedPassword
    if username == "admin":
        if password == storedPassword:
            messagebox.showinfo("Login Successful!","Welcome Admin")
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Login Failed!","Wrong Password")
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Login Failed!","Wrong Username")

def cpass():
    global window
    window.destroy()
    window = Tk()
    Label(window,text="Enter new password:").pack()
    passn = Entry(window,width=15)
    passn.pack()
    Button(window,text="OK",command=lambda:chgpass(passn.get())).pack()
    window.mainloop()

def chgpass(newpass):
    global window
    global storedPassword
    storedPassword = newpass
    window.destroy()
    login()

def login():
    global window
    window = Tk()
    Label(window,text="Username:").pack()
    usern = Entry(window,width=15)
    usern.pack()
    Label(window,text="Password:").pack()
    passw = Entry(window,width=15,show="*")
    passw.pack()
    Button(window,text="Login",command=lambda:loginok(usern.get(),passw.get())).pack()
    Button(window,text="Forgot",command=cpass).pack()
    window.mainloop()

login()
```